# Stop the evil eye from glaring at me!

Tags: cipher

My sister gave me a message today:

```
13.8  4.8   3     10.8  3     11.4
7.8   15    0     0     0     0
1.8   9     9     6.6   5.4   3
```

She's glaring at me with an [evil eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvVQr.jpg). (My fault I decided to get her one anyway.)

I better figure this out quickly. **What on earth does this say?**

**Note:** She has sworn that the plaintext is not offensive, just incredibly boring.

Comment: Any clue whether those non-integer numbers are exact or could be just rounded to 1 d.p.? If they're exact, multiplying everything by 5 could be involved.

Comment: @randal'thor They are exact. You should not use any rounding.

Comment: Would something to do with an oboe make sense?

Comment: @randal'thor Nothing to do with music.

Comment: Is the story part actually real?  If yes, I definitely understand....  Argh...  Sisters

Comment: @AJL Only the ciphertext is not real. She told me how to encode it and the plaintext, and I encrypted it for her.

Comment: Surprising no one has found the solution yet. Looks like I underestimated her intelligence...

Comment: Can the message be deciphered without the picture?

Comment: @DevOfZot Yes, the picture has nothing to do with the message. It's purely for storytelling purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She's wondering

> WHERES MY COOKIE

You get there by

> dividing each number by 0.6 and using the result as index to the alphabet, e.g. 13.8 / 0.6 = 23 => W.

Comment: Don't worry, I got her the cookie already :)